# Omnisharp error: It was not possible to find any installed dotnet SDKs

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04, omnisharp

I installed two .net core sdk versions in my ubuntu pc, because I had some projects running in .net core 3.1 and 2.2 under the same solution.
Run new apps through the terminal is fine, but this message always appears in visual studio code

[image]

And the code is marked with error

[image]

How can I use two sdks in the same machine and run .net apps normally?